# Raspberry Pi Zero - MotionEye Camera

Tags: raspberry-pi, motioneyeos

Been setting up a `Pi Zero` with the latest `Raspbian` and `Motioneye 4.2.2.`

After setting things up, I needed extra space to store videos.

Got a new larger SD card and flashed the existing image (with `Motioneye` installed) to the new larger SD card.

Unforunately, `Motioneye` still thinks I have the same amount of space and isn't storing any more files than the original size of the old SD card.

Do I have to re-install `Motioneye` for it to see the new space?

-DP

Comment: This might be a great question for the Raspberry PI Stack exchange site: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> sudo raspi-config

and navigate to

Advanced Options -> Expand Filesystem -> OK

> sudo reboot now